# Battery issue with Macbook pro retina

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, battery

I have a MacBook Pro Retina Early 2015 model, that I have owned for 2 years. It was working absolutely fine just yesterday (or the day before). I consulted an Apple authorized service center that said I needed to replace the battery but I was confused how could the battery die overnight. So I contacted another Apple authorized service center. They took in my laptop for diagnosis for a couple of days and told me that the "topcase" was faulty and needed to be replaced. Of course they are also charging a hefty sum of money for it.

I have two questions:

1. What is a topcase? (sorry i am slightly technologically challenged)
2. Is there any way around my problem. I really don't think I can afford a new top case.

My laptop works fine on AC power, it's just that it's not a laptop anymore if I always have to keep it plugged in.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The top case (or Upper Case Assembly) is essentially the case that contains the keyboard and trackpad. In some models, when replacing the battery, Apple will replace this as well.

In terms of other ways around your problem, you *could* try resetting the System Management Controller (SMC) to see if that has any impact. To give this a try, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your Mac
2. Unplug the power cable from your Mac
3. For 10 seconds, press and hold at the same time the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> keys (on the **left** side of the **built-in** keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. After 10 seconds let go of all keys and the power button
5. Plug in the power cable
6. Turn your Mac back on with the power button.